# How to parametrize UIView animation?

Tags: objective-c, animation

I have lot of such case statements which would fire various UIView animations. I would like to write a module and parametrize these so I don't have to repeat similar code over and over. What is the best way to pass (parametrized) values for animationRepeatCount & animationDuration?

```
case 10: //Animation Number 10
    //.........
    imageAnimation2.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"monkey_dancing_01.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"monkey_dancing_02.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"monkey_dancing_03.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"monkey_dancing_04.png"],
                                      nil];
    imageAnimation2.animationRepeatCount = 4;
    imageAnimation2.animationDuration = 2;
    [imageAnimation2 startAnimating];
    [self loadSoundEffectAudio:@"Monkey_10"];
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopSoundEffectAudio) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];
    break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how regular your assets and animations are, you could make some utility methods to handle much of that.

Like say:

```
+ (void) loadAnimation:(UIImageView *)imageView name:(NSString *)filename
{
    NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIImage * image;
    int index = 1;
    NSString * string;

    do
    {
        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%04d.png", filename, index++];
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:string];
        if(image)
            [array addObject:image];
    } while (image != nil);

    imageView.animationImages = array;
    imageView.animationDuration = [array count] / 18;
    [array release];
}
```

The above code loads up animations into an array with very regular naming conventions (XXXX.png). They are also all based on the same framerate so I can build the duration at the same time.

Comment: Thanks EricLeaf. That's helpful. I am curious, why did you divide `[array count]` by 18 to get animationDuration? If I want to pass  int parameters for animationRepeatCount & animationDuration to loadAnimation: function, would that work or do I have to convert into into corresponding value before I assign them to animationRepeatCount & animationDuration?

Comment: @Alex, in that case the animations were 18 frames per second.

Also I don't bother sending single parameters when you can just as easily set them on the object you are sending. This was just to do the file loading work, no real point in sending a hugh list of parameters just to set some properties.